# Find rows that contain three digit number

Tags: regex, r

I need to subset rows that contain  *`<three digit number>`*
I wrote

```
foo <- grepl("<^[0-9]{3}$>", log1[,2])
others <- log1[!foo,]
```

but I'm not really sure how to use regex...just been using cheat sheets and Google. I think the < and > characters are throwing it off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `^` and `$` signs refer to the beginning and end of the string, respectively. You shouldn't be matching anything before or after them.

If you want rows that **contain** that pattern, you shouldn't use the anchors at all. You should just use this: `<[0-9]{3}>` (or shorten it to `<\\d{3}>`)

Comment: Thank you for your addition, that's what I was trying to do but I got this error: `Error: '\d' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""<\d"`

Comment: @camelarms: sorry, I guess r regex doesn't support that shorthand for digits. I will switch it back to `[0-9]`.

Comment: @arshajii: thank you; I'm not familiar with r so my assumption was that it didn't support it.

Comment: The issue is that R is parsing your string before sending it onto the regex function.  That means the \ gets read as an instruction by the R parser.  You have to use \\ to tell R that the \ is literal and to pass \ to the regex.

Answer (score 6):

You almost had it. Try

```
^<[0-9]{3}>$
```

It might behoove you to read about [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) (`^` and `$`).

Answer (score 1):

Just for posterity, I thought I would contribute what I think is the implied answer to the OP's stated question.

It seems the OP wants to exclude rows of a data frame where the second column contains a 3-digit integer.  This can be done quite easily using the 'nchar' function to count the number of characters in each number, like so:

```
others <- log1[nchar(log1[,2])!=3,]
```

We are simply creating an array with the number of characters contained in each row of column 2 and selecting that row if the number does not equal 3.